# Play a sound file in WPF app

Tags: wpf

I put a sound file stored in the database as a `Byte[]` .Now,I want to play this sound file in my WPF program. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to do something like the following:

```
private void PlaySoundFromBytes(byte[] rawSoundBytes)
{
    Stream rawStream = new MemoryStream(rawSoundBytes);
    var player = new SoundPlayer(rawStream);
    player.Play();
}
```

Comment: Thank you.By the way,what time is it now?

Comment: Did this answer work for you? If so close, mark it as the answer.

Comment: How does the `SoundPlayer` know what sample rate and bit depth to play the raw bytes at?

Comment: SoundPlayer is using the WAV file format that contains metadata about the audio. You can find some file format documentation here: http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/WAVE.html